# How do I refactor my code and make it more readable and clean using async/await instead of callbacks?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

I have these following controller functions, and I want to make it more clean and maintainable.
Probably by using `async/await` and `exec()`.  Also, the validations do not look not good. It would be great if you suggested me good practices to refactor this.

```js
   registerUser: (req, res) => {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body
        User.create(req.body, (err, createdUser) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error occurred" })
            } else if (!username || !email || !password) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Username, email and password are must" })
            } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invaid email" })
            } else if (password.length < 6) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password should be of at least 6 characters" })
            }
            else {
                return res.status(200).json({ user: createdUser })
            }
        })
    },

    loginUser: async (req, res, next) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body

        if (!email || !password) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email and password are must" })
        }

        await User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) { 
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email" })
            } else if (!user) {
                return res.status(402).json({ error: "User not found" })
            } else if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
                return res.status(402).json({ error: "incorrect password" })
            } 

        })
    }
```

Comment: If this is working code that you want improvement suggestions, then the proper place to post is http://codereview.stackexchange.com after you read the posting rules there.

Comment: For starters, don't use both `await` and a callback on `await User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {...})`.  If you pass a callback, then `User.findOne()` does NOT return a promise and therefore the `await` is useless.  Or if you want to use `await`, don't pass a callback, get the return value from the `await` and use `try/catch` for error handling.  Pick one way or the other.  Can't do half of both.  Other than that, there isn't a lot else to change.  You only have one asnchronous operation in each function so things aren't simplified much by using `await` instead of a callback.

Comment: Post on codereview for other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code should be like this**

```
registerUser: async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body
        if (!username || !email || !password) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Username, email and password are must" })
        }
        if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invaid email" })
        }
        if (password.length < 6) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password should be of at least 6 characters" })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ user: await User.create({ username, email, password }) })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error occurred" })
    }
},

loginUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body

        if (!email || !password) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email and password are must" })
        }

        if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email" })
        }

        const user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(402).json({ message: "User not found" })
        }

        if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
            return res.status(402).json({ message: "incorrect password" })
        }


        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login Success" })
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error)
    }
}
```

**But you se @hapi/joi for Schemas validation. then your code will be this**

```
registerUser: async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body
        return res.status(200).json({ user: await User.create({ username, email, password }) })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error occurred" })
    }
},

loginUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(402).json({ message: "User not found" })
        }

        if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
            return res.status(402).json({ message: "incorrect password" })
        }

        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login Success" })
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personnaly create a `User` class in order to handle User related actions. I do prefer separate the express from the database model.

Look at the following, feel free to ask any question you may have :)

```
// Special classes to differentiate the error types
// and finally returns the appropriate code from express
class Error400 extends Error {
  constructor(msg) {
    super(msg);

    this.httpErrorCode = 400;
  }
}

class Error500 extends Error {
  constructor(msg) {
    super(msg);

    this.httpErrorCode = 500;
  }
}

// User class holding every User related actions
class User {
  model = ...

  createUser({
    username,
    email,
    password,
  }) {
    if (!username || !email || !password) {
      throw new Error400('Username, email and password are must');
    }

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      throw new Error400('Invaid email');
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      throw new Error400('Password should be of at least 6 characters');
    }

    try {
      return this.model.create({
        username,
        email,
        password,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error500('Server error occurred');
    }
  }
}

// Express
registerUser: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    return res.status(200).json({
       user: await User.create(req.body)
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(err.httpErrorCode).json({
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
});
```